# How to exclude general criteria value from group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, informix

I have two tables :

> One for employees data `Employee`
>
> Another for employee vacations balance  `VacBal`

Now i want to get the current vacation balance for each employee,considering if the `emp_num = 0` then it's a `general balance` for all employees not for specific employee

---

> If Employee table Sample data like that :

```
emp_num   name
  546     john
  134     Ramy
```

and

> VacBal like that

```
emp_num  bal_num  bal_date
  546      1       5-5-2015
  546      2       6-5-2015
  134      1       7-5-2015
  0        3       2-2-2015
  0        4       6-1-2015
```

I want result set like this :

```
emp_num  name  SUM(bal_num)
546      john    10             --->3+7
134      Ramy     8             --->1+7
```

How to do this ?

Comment: BTW, are you really using both MS SQL Server and Informix? (Very rare combination.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query to `SUM`:

```
select e.emp_num, e.name, (select sum(vb.bal_num) from VacBal vb
                           where vb.emp_num in (e.emp_num,0))
from Employee e
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT e.emp_num, 
       name, 
       Sum(bal_num) + (SELECT Sum(bal_num) 
                       FROM   vacbal vb 
                       WHERE  emp_num = 0) 
FROM   employee e
          inner join vacbal v on e.emp_num=v.emp_num
GROUP  BY e.emp_num, 
          name
```

Comment: ` Sum(bal_num) ` doesn't exist in `employee ` table